# app with changeable buttons

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I am working on an app which will have a scroll view with buttons in it(all different company icons). All the buttons will call the same activity, (the user will not know this). The question is as follows:

I need to be able to add buttons and remove buttons without users having to update the app all the time. How can i do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: read button config from a database?

Comment: Can that be done and can you point me to some documentation, get button config from a database

Comment: Well, I was thinking that you could dynamically create buttons. You could read button config data from a database and depending on what you read you would create a buttona and set its params. For example, you add two buttons to your button table with text, width, and height being the parameters.

foreach button{
button newbutton = new button()
newbutton.setText("texst")
etc...

layout.add(newbutton);

}

Just one idea...not sure how efficient it is!

Answer (score 0):

Button.setVisibility(int visibility)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29

Comment: Thanks busy having a look at button.setVisibility(int visibility)

Comment: I'm not sure that this answers OP's question. Unless the visibility is being set based on some external configuration, the user will have to update the app in order for the visibility to change. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Hey BarbiePylon, let me try explain better. If I have a list view and populate the list with data from mysql through a web service,lets say a list of employee names, and i select a persons name, and can populate the view with more data from the database regarding that person. In stead of getting data from the database when selecting a persons name, i need to call a new activity.